# Can I have the extlib name picker running in xPINC lookup the directory on the server?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpinc

Is it possible to use the name picker in the extlib in an xPINC app, to pick from the server side address book? Currently running in the browser I am able to pull from the server side names.nsf, and while running as xpinc I pull the local names.nsf.

Do you know if this is possible? Really trying to accomplish "write once run everywhere".

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="djextNameTextBox3">
<xe:this.dataProvider>
    <xe:dominoNABNamePicker groups="false"
        nameList="peopleByLastName" people="true"
        addressBookSel="db-name" addressBookDb="names.nsf">
    </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
</xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify a different server you would do the following.

```
addressBookDb="SERVER!!names.nsf"
```

I recommend reading the "XPages Extension Library. A Step-by-Step Guide to the next generation of XPages Components" as it details this component more (Page 165).

Comment: I should pick up that book. Thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 2):

With IBM Notes 9.0 there's a new "Run on Server" option that allows remote XPages applications to run directly on the Domino server. I am not sure how it affects address book lookups using the name picker control. But give it a try.

[image]

Comment: Its funny I tried this away from the office and it ended up going to a website with a similar name to my internal server name.

Comment: I am assuming that option runs the xPage as a web page. Do you know if there is any documentation on that feature?

Comment: XPages in the Notes client is run as web pages (with XULRunner as browser) for both local and remote.

Comment: That option just changes what actually does the rendering if its on the server or if its on the client. I am going to call IBM about this but if you are interested; my servername is cityname.domain.com or cityname/domain, when I enabled that option my app opened up to cityname.com which is a site about the city not my company site. Interesting, again thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering if that would affect what address book the name picker uses. I'm glad that Simon could help

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any Xpinc development because we do it all via browser, but you might try the viewpicklist control on openntf. I will ask Mark tomorrow to be sure and post his answer, but in the meantime you could give it a whirl.

Comment: I forgot about that control. I should implement that in some projects.

Comment: Mark told me today that he believes it does