# Extension Library Name Picker gets local Names.nsf even though DB is on server

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a Name Picker on an XPage with a dataProvider dominoNABNamePicker with the addressBookSel = all-public and people and groups = true. With the database on a Domino server using the Notes Client it displays my local Names.nsf. If I open the DB in a brouse it selects the correct names.nsf from the server.
Can't figure out if this is the result of settings in my client, the server or XPages. Does the same thing on two different PC's.
I would think that the all-public would force it to open only public NABs but it does not appear so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have the extlib name picker running in xPINC lookup the directory on the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430667/can-i-have-the-extlib-name-picker-running-in-xpinc-lookup-the-directory-on-the-s)

Comment: I guess it is some what, but hard coding the server name is not a good option, plus the server may have more than one public NAB on it. I tried the dominoViewNamePicker and that works OK, and that works for the Notes Client, but still does not address the issue of multiple NABs. Trying to write this as a general case to get the server names from the session then get all the NABS and loop through them and get the public ones. addressBookDb does not take an Array. Plus don't think the serverName!!names.nsf works in the web browser. The generic NamePicker works fine in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question myself.

The answer, in the control add
addressBookDb="SERVER!!names.nsf"

From here.

[Can I have the extlib name picker running in xPINC lookup the directory on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430667/can-i-have-the-extlib-name-picker-running-in-xpinc-lookup-the-directory-on-the-s)

Answer (score 0):

After a fair bit of frustration I have this working for the Notes Client and the Web Client. Perhaps this is obvious to most of you, but it sure wasn't to me.
First on the Name Picker I created a namePickerAggregator. Then I added a dominoNABNamePicker
in the addressBookDb I put the following SSJS:

```
var server:String = @Name("[CN]",session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer());
var allNABs:Array = session.getAddressBooks().iterator();
var pubNABs = new Array;
var privNABs = new Array;
while (allNABs.hasNext()) {
    var db:NotesDatabase = allNABs.next();
    if (db.isPublicAddressBook()){
        pubNABs.push(db.getFileName())
    } else {
        privNABs.push(db.getFileName())
    }
    db.recycle()
}


   if (pubNABs[0] == ""){
    return privNames[0];
    break;
} else {
    return server + "!!" + pubNABs[0];
    break
}
```

I then added a second dominoNABNamePicker with the same block of code except the return is

```
if (pubNABs[1] != "") {
    return server + "!!" + pubNABs[1];
    break;
} else {
    return "";
}
```

This code works for both the Notes Client and the Web client so I'm now a happy camper, unless I find a gotcha somewhere.

Comment: spoke a bit to soon. As I'm trying to write a generalized case I created a Third dominoNABNamePicker that resolved to "" because the there are only two Public NABs on the server, the code then returns an error when I try opening the document. Is there a way to disable a dominoNABNamePicker?

Comment: Got it done by making multiple NamePicker controls with different number of dominoNABNamePicker providers based on teh number of address books returned by session.getAddressBooks and then iterating through them and makeing a list of Public and Private NABs. Needed a seperate set of name pickers for public and private then set the rendered property appropriately. Probably a better way of doing it but this works OK

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I eventually did. I set a limit on the maximum number of address books (not great but it works) of 4 you can create as many as you want. So I created a couple of sessionScope variable that I created in the after Page Loads event on the XPage. I used this formula.

```
var allNABs:Array = session.getAddressBooks().iterator();
var pubNABs = new Array;
var privNABs = new Array;
while (allNABs.hasNext()) {
    var db:NotesDatabase = allNABs.next();
    if (db.isPublicAddressBook()){
        pubNABs.push(db.getFilePath())
    } else {
        privNABs.push(db.getFilePath())
    }
    db.recycle()
}
sessionScope.put("ssPublicNABs", pubNABs);
sessionScope.put("ssPrivateNABs", privNABs);
```

because I use several different Name Pickers on the same page I did not want to repeat having to cycle through the Address books. 
Then I created 4 NamePicker controls and added 1, 2 , 3 and 4 dominoNABNamePickers providers to each of the successive controls. Then set the rendered property based on the number of public Address books so they would not blow up on me. The db name property on each of the providers is :

```
var server:String = @Name("[CN]",session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer());
var pubNABs:Array = sessionScope.get("ssPublicNABs");
    return server + "!!" + pubNABs[0];
```

where pubNABs[n] returns the correct filePath for the NAB. It works well in both Notes Client and the Web.
Then to make it not blow up on a local disconnected replica I created 4 more controls and did the same thing but used the privNABs with appropriate rendered properties so that there is no conflict. Seems like the long way around and I'm sure that there is an easier way, but it works.