# xpages name picker in XPiNC

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="djTextarea5">
            <xe:this.dataProvider>
                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker groups="false"
                    nameList="peopleByLastName" addressBookDb="names.nsf">
                </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
            </xe:this.dataProvider>
        </xe:namePicker>
```

It works on browser without the `addressBookDb="names.nsf"`, but in Client Notes it doesn't, when I click the Name picker: my list is empty.

I appreciate your time!

I saw the [Can I have the extlib name picker running in xPINC lookup the directory on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430667/can-i-have-the-extlib-name-picker-running-in-xpinc-lookup-the-directory-on-the-s) with the explanation : `adressBookDb="SERVER!!names.nsf"` but it doesn't works in client Notes.

Answer (score 1):

You need addressBookDb="SERVER!!names.nsf" addressBookSel="db-name".

The hover help on addressBookDb clarifies that it only works if addressBookSel is db-name